# Tokenzing multi words in entire corpus

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, data-science

I'm new to NLTK and was wondering if anyone would be able to help me in solving the following situation:

I'm working on a corpus of new articles and have texts in the following format:

t= "While at a rally in Wilmington, Republican presidential nominee Donald Trump made a clear insinuation that Democratic nominee Hillary Clinton has to keep away from becoming president"

and have following code in place:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import MWETokenizer
mwetokenizer = MWETokenizer([('Donald','Trump')], separator=' ')
mwetokenizer.add_mwe(('Hillary','Clinton'))
mwetokenized_sentence = mwetokenizer.tokenize(word_tokenize(t))
print(mwetokenized_sentence)
```

Which gives the following result:

['While', 'at', 'a', 'rally', 'in', 'Wilmington', ',', 'Republican', 'presidential', 'nominee', 'Donald Trump', 'made', 'a', 'clear', 'insinuation', 'that', 'Democratic', 'nominee', 'Hillary Clinton', 'has', 'to', 'keep', 'away', 'from', 'becoming', 'president']

As we can see the words "Hillary Clinton" and "Donald trump" are together which is as required/expected.

Is there any way that I can figure out similar multi-words in an entire corpus of sentences without looking at individual text?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to merge are proper nouns, then I suggest you to use Named Entity Recognition techniques (check out [spacy library](https://spacy.io) and [its usage per NER](https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-ner-using-spacy-nlp-part-4-28da2ece57c6)):

```
import spacy

my_sentence = "While at a rally in Wilmington, Republican presidential nominee Donald Trump made a clear insinuation that Democratic nominee Hilary Clinton has to keep away from becoming president."

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg') # you have several models to choose from
doc = nlp(my_sentence)
print([(ent, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents])

$> [(Wilmington, 'GPE'), (Republican, 'NORP'), (Donald Trump, 'PERSON'), (Democratic, 'NORP'), (Hilary Clinton, 'PERSON')]
```

If are more interested in merging together often occurring sequences of tokens which are likely to convey a meaning on their own (`New York City`, `Department of Justice` and similar) than you can use the [Phrases class](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html) in the [gensim library](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/).

Finally, if the entities you're looking for are mainly covered by Wikipedia articles, then you may want to try [DBPedia Spotlight](http://spotlight.dbpedia.org). Not only will detect `Donal Trump` phrase but it will also link it to its Wikipedia page. It works for any type of concept, not just PERSONs.

Comment: I've added a small snippet of code for the spacy library usage.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
    for ent in doc.ents:
        retokenizer.merge(doc[ent.start:ent.end])
```

In fact, you can use spacy to remove punctuations & stop words, and perform lemmatization too!

```
parser = spacy.load('de_core_news_sm')
def tokenize(text):
    doc = parser(text)
    with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
        for ent in doc.ents:
            retokenizer.merge(doc[ent.start:ent.end], attrs={"LEMMA": ent.text})
    return [x.lemma_ for x in doc if not x.is_punct and not x.is_stop]
```

Example:

```
>>> text = "Jochen Schweizer ist eines der interessantesten Unternehmen der Welt, hat den Sitz allerdings nicht in der Schweizerischen Eidgenossenschaft."
>>> print(tokenize(text))
>>> [u'Jochen Schweizer', u'interessant', u'Unternehmen', u'Welt', u'Sitz', u'Schwe
```